# OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: python, raspberry-pi4, openblas, yolov5

I'm running [YOLOv5](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5) tool on Raspberry Pi 4 Model B (4GB RAM) over Manjaro OS (arm manjaro).
After installing all the requirements for this specific architecture (aarch64) needed by the tool it's doing inference task (detect.py file) very well, but I've got a problem besides it's working slow (around 1-2 seconds per frame), it shows this:

```
OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang. Please rebuild the library with USE_OPENMP=1 option.
```

like 15 times. But I'm not exactly sure what is causing this trouble if it's torch, opencv or another library that is calling OpenBLAS (I don't even know what is OpenBLAS used for) but I'm afraid the error should be in one of this lines.

```
# detect.py # Process detections

    for i, det in enumerate(pred):  # detections per image
        if webcam:  # batch_size >= 1
            p, s, im0, frame = path[i], '%g: ' % i, im0s[i].copy(), dataset.count
        else:
            p, s, im0, frame = path, '', im0s, getattr(dataset, 'frame', 0)
        p = Path(p)  # to Path
        save_path = str(save_dir / p.name)  # img.jpg
        txt_path = str(save_dir / 'labels' / p.stem) + ('' if dataset.mode == 'image' else f'_{frame}')  # img.txt
        s += '%gx%g ' % img.shape[2:]  # print string
        gn = torch.tensor(im0.shape)[[1, 0, 1, 0]]  # normalization gain whwh
        if len(det):
            # Rescale boxes from img_size to im0 size
            det[:, :4] = scale_coords(img.shape[2:], det[:, :4], im0.shape).round()
            # Print results
            for c in det[:, -1].unique():
                n = (det[:, -1] == c).sum()  # detections per class
                s += f"{n} {names[int(c)]}{'s' * (n > 1)}, "  # add to string
            # Write results
            for *xyxy, conf, cls in reversed(det):
                if save_txt:  # Write to file
                    xywh = (xyxy2xywh(torch.tensor(xyxy).view(1, 4)) / gn).view(-1).tolist()  # normalized xywh
                    line = (cls, *xywh, conf) if opt.save_conf else (cls, *xywh)  # label format
                    with open(txt_path + '.txt', 'a') as f:
                        f.write(('%g ' * len(line)).rstrip() % line + '\n')
                if save_img or view_img:  # Add bbox to image
                    label = f'{names[int(cls)]} {conf:.2f}'
                    plot_one_box(xyxy, im0, label=label, color=colors[int(cls)], line_thickness=3)
```

since after finish inference (detections) it shows the next part of the script which it's the time that the inference took.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Have you solved it? I have the same problem with original detect.py file